# Justify alignment of images in rows (ala Google Images)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to justify images across a fixed width (exactly how google images does it, eg: [here](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=image&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1018&bih=959&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=ynNgT8XpDoqt0QXZn7H-Bg))

Is there a somewhat simple solution for this?

The last resort would be to write a jquery script that calculates how many images it can fit into a row and iterates individually through the images. Seems sort of overkill for something that can be accomplished with text using text-align:justify...

Comment: Lets see how far have you reached :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  display: inline-block; for elements with images and text-align: justify; for parent element.
Example:

```
<ul class="images">
    <li><img src="..."/></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

and CSS:

```
.images{text-align: justify;}
.images li{display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: perfect! you just saved me an hour and the internet from a bloated jquery plugin.

Comment: Can you provide a JsFiddle? This does not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you look for a powerful tool to justify images across a fixed width, this jQuery plugin may help you: https://github.com/brunjo/rowGrid.js

**[Demo](http://brunjo.github.io/rowGrid.js/)**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an outer container defined say a div or section with fixed width and try to float the image container within it to achieve it

```
<div id="outer-container" style="width:800px;height:400px;">
   <div id="image-container" style="float:left;width:100;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;">
      <img  src="your_image_src" width="100" height="100"/>
   </div>
   <div id="image-container" style="float:left;width:100;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;">
      <img  src="your_image_src" width="100" height="100"/>
   </div>
   <div id="image-container" style="float:left;width:100;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;">
      <img  src="your_image_src" width="100" height="100"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

You may use display:inline-block instead of float:left to achieve it.but display:inline-block can be used based on your situation.

Comment: this would work ....if each image is sized the identically and that the container never resizes. :) unfortunately i need something more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

On the long run it'll have many issues that is initially unthought of. Check out my plugin Justified Image Grid (do a google search). I did my best to replicate how flickr shows it with dynamic row height and minimal cropping.